# Errbit LDAP Authentication not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, authentication, devise, ldap

I'm trying to install errbit to track bugs more easily.

I followed the Installation Instructions from:

https://github.com/errbit/errbit

and

Installed the LDAP Authentication gem:

Gemfile:

```
gem "devise_ldap_authenticatable", :git => "git://github.com/cschiewek/devise_ldap_authenticatable.git"
```

executed:

```
rails generate devise_ldap_authenticatable:install
```

So far everything went good. The Unicorn Application Server starts without any issues.
But If I login I get this message:

```
Problem:
  Validation of User failed.
Summary:
   The following errors were found: Email can't be blank, Name can't be blank
Resolution:
   Try persisting the document with valid data or remove the validations.
```

Stack Trace:

```
mongoid (3.1.5) lib/mongoid/persistence.rb:335:in `fail_validate!'
mongoid (3.1.5) lib/mongoid/persistence.rb:97:in `save!'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/bundler/gems/devise_ldap_authenticatable-350b78431dbf/lib/devise_ldap_authenticatable/model.rb:107:in `find_for_ldap_authentication'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/bundler/gems/devise_ldap_authenticatable-350b78431dbf/lib/devise_ldap_authenticatable/strategy.rb:7:in `authenticate!'
warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/strategies/base.rb:53:in `_run!'
warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/proxy.rb:354:in `block in _run_strategies_for'
warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/proxy.rb:349:in `each'
warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/proxy.rb:349:in `_run_strategies_for'
warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/proxy.rb:319:in `_perform_authentication'
warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/proxy.rb:104:in `authenticate'
devise (3.1.1) lib/devise/controllers/helpers.rb:56:in `current_user'
devise (3.1.1) lib/devise/controllers/helpers.rb:52:in `user_signed_in?'
app/controllers/application_controller.rb:49:in `set_time_zone'
activesupport (3.2.18) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:484:in `_run__372840598407275581__process_action__1401166438855027473__callbacks'
activesupport (3.2.18) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
activesupport (3.2.18) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_process_action_callbacks'
activesupport (3.2.18) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (3.2.18) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:17:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.2.18) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.2.18) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (3.2.18) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (3.2.18) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
activesupport (3.2.18) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `instrument'
actionpack (3.2.18) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:29:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.2.18) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:207:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.2.18) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:121:in `process'
actionpack (3.2.18) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:45:in `process'
actionpack (3.2.18) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:203:in `dispatch'
actionpack (3.2.18) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:14:in `dispatch'
actionpack (3.2.18) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:246:in `block in action'
actionpack (3.2.18) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:73:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.18) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:73:in `dispatch'
actionpack (3.2.18) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:36:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.18) lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:43:in `call'
journey (1.0.4) lib/journey/router.rb:68:in `block in call'
journey (1.0.4) lib/journey/router.rb:56:in `each'
journey (1.0.4) lib/journey/router.rb:56:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.18) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:608:in `call'
rack-ssl-enforcer (0.2.6) lib/rack/ssl-enforcer.rb:51:in `call'
hoptoad_notifier (2.4.11) lib/hoptoad_notifier/rack.rb:27:in `call'
mongoid (3.1.5) lib/rack/mongoid/middleware/identity_map.rb:34:in `block in call'
mongoid (3.1.5) lib/mongoid/unit_of_work.rb:39:in `unit_of_work'
mongoid (3.1.5) lib/rack/mongoid/middleware/identity_map.rb:34:in `call'
warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `block in call'
warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `catch'
warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.18) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/best_standards_support.rb:17:in `call'
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call'
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:35:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.18) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/head.rb:14:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.18) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:21:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.18) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:242:in `call'
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:210:in `context'
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:205:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.18) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:341:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.18) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:28:in `block in call'
activesupport (3.2.18) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `_run__2041107628848191489__call__2819675434513924104__callbacks'
activesupport (3.2.18) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
activesupport (3.2.18) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_call_callbacks'
activesupport (3.2.18) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (3.2.18) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:102:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.18) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:31:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.18) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:16:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.18) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:56:in `call'
railties (3.2.18) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:32:in `call_app'
railties (3.2.18) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `block in call'
activesupport (3.2.18) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:22:in `tagged'
railties (3.2.18) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.18) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:22:in `call'
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
activesupport (3.2.18) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72:in `call'
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/lock.rb:15:in `call'
rack-cache (1.2) lib/rack/cache/context.rb:136:in `forward'
rack-cache (1.2) lib/rack/cache/context.rb:143:in `pass'
rack-cache (1.2) lib/rack/cache/context.rb:155:in `invalidate'
rack-cache (1.2) lib/rack/cache/context.rb:71:in `call!'
rack-cache (1.2) lib/rack/cache/context.rb:51:in `call'
hoptoad_notifier (2.4.11) lib/hoptoad_notifier/user_informer.rb:12:in `call'
railties (3.2.18) lib/rails/engine.rb:484:in `call'
railties (3.2.18) lib/rails/application.rb:231:in `call'
railties (3.2.18) lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/deflater.rb:13:in `call'
unicorn (4.6.3) lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:552:in `process_client'
unicorn (4.6.3) lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:632:in `worker_loop'
unicorn (4.6.3) lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:500:in `spawn_missing_workers'
unicorn (4.6.3) lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:142:in `start'
unicorn (4.6.3) bin/unicorn_rails:209:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/bin/unicorn_rails:23:in `load'
/usr/local/bin/unicorn_rails:23:in `<main>'
```

Request Parameters

```
{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>"0000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
 "user"=>{"username"=>"chris",
 "password"=>"[FILTERED]",
 "remember_me"=>"0"}}
```

What did I do wrong?

**Update:**

It works now so far.
But I'm still gitting one more Issue:

```
Mongoid::Errors::Validations (
Problem:
  Validation of User failed.
Summary:
  The following errors were found: Name can't be blank
Resolution:
  Try persisting the document with valid data or remove the validations.):
  app/controllers/application_controller.rb:48:in `set_time_zone'
```

I tried to remove the LDAP Validation, but that also didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sorry if this answer comes too late. Here's what I did to get a working LDAP setup.

In app/models/users.rb I added the following method:

```
  def ldap_before_save
    name = Devise::LDAP::Adapter.get_ldap_param(self.username, "givenName")
    surname = Devise::LDAP::Adapter.get_ldap_param(self.username, "sn")
    mail = Devise::LDAP::Adapter.get_ldap_param(self.username, "mail")

    self.name = (name + surname).join ' '
    self.email = mail.first
  end
```

In config/initializers/devise.rb, set the following params

```
  config.ldap_create_user = true
  config.ldap_use_admin_to_bind = true
```

Create a new file config/initializers/devise_ldap.rb with the following contents:

```
  Errbit::Config.devise_modules << :ldap_authenticatable
```

For more details, read https://github.com/errbit/errbit#configuring-ldap-authentication

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help. But I still get one error message. I added it to the Original request